# How to show the full word while type the letters in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, show, keyword

It is very difficult for me. I want to show the full related word for the typing letters in iphone app. Means, if the user enter the letter `'st'` (`UITextField`)the app should show the related words for the st like `stack, stock, stop and so on`. This format like this the `entered letters must be in Black and other suggestion letters in light gray color`. How to store all the words in local for this? Please help me to solve this work. I am struggling in this work. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are almost talking about creating something like dictionary and then filtering words out.There must be something like a service which will return you this or something from where you can fetch and store all english words to you local sqlite database.

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal Thanks for your spot response. Can you please help to store all english words in local. Thanks.

Comment: Storing it in a local stuff is not a big deal,but the point is from where will you get all the english words.You cannot keep on inserting all the values in database explicitly.

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal thanks for you response. Now am going to test the functionality with sample words. If it is succeeded i will include all english words by some other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you (I have never tried this so can't give any reviews):
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/doautocompletetextfield

Another tutorial that you may want to look at, although its not exactly what you want:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. It seems looking what i want . I will incorporate this in my project. Thanks.